# Spring Cloud Dataflow deployment on premises Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm deploying Spring Cloud Dataflow 1.4.0.RELEASE on my org's Cloud Foundry. I took the CF deployable server and used a manifest to deploy it. We use it mostly for `tasks` developed using Spring Cloud Task. In the documentation (that uses PCF) suggests this configuration:

`SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_SERVICES my_mysql`

Where `my_mysql` is the DB to keep track of task related information. Documentation suggests using this as CF's `cups` but that won't work since my org uses Vault to store keys and secrets so DB connections are not allowed in such way. 
Since I did not provided any value for `SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_SERVICES` in my manifest when I start SPDF it throws an error indicating that `bean "taskService" could not be created`. 
Haven't found a workaround for this. Is this the only way to specify DB connection for tasks in version 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a deployment property when launching the task:

`task launch --name mytask --properties "deployer.mytask.cloudfoundry.services=-Duser.timezone=my_mysql"`

This way, you don't have to use the server level environment property `SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_SERVICES`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem so far is I'm not sure how the `user provided service` should look to be meaningful for SCDF. In the documentation the service is created from marketplace but in my org CF deployment there is no marketplace so I'd have to create a user provided service yet not sure what fields, format, etc should I use